# Show that the sum of (outdeg(v)-indeg(v))=0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E,\Phi)$ a directed graph. Let $outdeg(v)=\#\{e \in E| source(e) = v\}$ and $indeg(v)=\#\{e \in E| sink(e) = v\}$. Show that $$\sum \limits_{v \in V}(outdeg(v)-indeg(v)) = 0$$

Can you help me how to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every arc in the graph adds $+1$ to the outdegree of exactly one node (the one from which it starts) and $+1$ to the indegree of exactly one node (the one where it arrives).

So your sum is actually

$$\sum_{e\in E} (+1-(+1))=0$$

**Added**: The above argument can be formalized using induction on the number of arcs:

- *Base step*: a graph with $0$ arcs.
- *Inductive*: You start from a graph with $n-1$ arcs and add one. The above argument yields that, if the sum was $0$, before, it remains $0$.

Comment: Or note that
$$\sum_{v\in V}(\operatorname{outdeg}(v)-\operatorname{indeg}(v))=\sum_{v\in V}(\sum_{w,vw\in E}1-\sum_{w,wv\in E}1)=\sum_{vw\in E}1-\sum_{wv\in E}1=0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph. Then in and out degrees of $i$'th vertex are:
    $$k_{i}^{in} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}$$ and $$k_{i}^{out} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}A_{ji}$$

Hence both $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}k_{i}^{in}$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}k_{i}^{out}$ are equal to the sum of all the elements of the adjacency matrix and so their difference is 0.